# Parity: Addresses, Contracts

Tags: parity

I noticed that Parity disabled the option to create a vanilla address. The only option available in my account is to create vaults, new accounts or multisig-wallets.

After seing Parity's art of contracting not being bullet proof I prefer to still use simple addresses.

Anybody know how I can do this?

Answer (score 0):

When you create an account, you are creating a new address with his public and private key, not a contract.

Comment: Thank you! But why do I always need a new seed? Can't I just create an address based on my previous seed?